# How to change table name in power bi programmatically

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want to change the table name of a particular detaset in Power BI  programmatically. There are set of REST APIs provided by Power BI, I tried using of [update_table_schema](http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/table/update-an-existing-tables-schema) APIs but with no success. I'm not able to change the table name.

Can anyone help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some more details to your question like the code block. And the area where you are facing trouble.

Comment: The PUT request to the table resource does not support updating the table name, only the underlying table schema. You can submit your ideas to Power BI in [user voice](https://ideas.powerbi.com).